# How do I set the size of an Array from a Global variable in VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6

Using the code below, I'm trying to set the size of an array.

```
   Private a3Tree(Globals.iTreeSize) As AL3TreeElement
```

I get the error "Constant Expression Required". Where

```
   Public iTreeSize As Integer
```

is in a "Globals" Module.

Comment: A global variable is not a constant.  Are you sure that is VB6?

Comment: Yes it is VB6. But can't I just pop an integer in there? The value of Globals.iTreeSize is set as 2500

Comment: Then declare it as a constant...I confess to being willfully forgetful of all the VB6 syntax but something like `Public Const iTreeSize As Integer = 2500`

Comment: The value for Globals.iTreeSize is being set elsewhere in the program. It wont always be 2500. I was just using that as an example. Sorry for the confusion. If I use "Public Const iTreeSize As Integer = Globals.iTreeSize"
I get the same error.

Comment: Then just declare it to set the scope: `Private a3Tree() As AL3TreeElement` and size it when you need it: `ReDim a3Tree(Globals.Treesize) As ...`

Comment: Well that works. I dont understand why. But at this point, I'm not sure I care. Thank you SO much. Put that into an answer and I'll happily vote it up.

Comment: As the error says, it needs a constant.  Constants are known at compile time;  Variables are not.  Go ahead and post your own answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Plutonix here is the answer...

***Then just declare it to set the scope: Private a3Tree() As AL3TreeElement and size it when you need it: ReDim a3Tree(Globals.Treesize) As ...***